# Angular nxg-translate with monorepo: merge translation files

Tags: angular, ngx-translate, nrwl-nx

The project is using NX monorepo structure. Right now there are three apps using three libs. All translation files for ngx-translate package are placed respectively at `apps/[app-name]/assets/i18n/[language].json`

Now I want to split these app translation files into several files to avoid repeating the translation strings, so there would be this structure:

```
apps
 |- [app]
       |-i18n
           | [lang].json
       |- assets
           |- i18n [empty at first]

libs
 |- [lib]
       |-i18n
           | [lang].json
```

The idea is that when an app is being built, a node(?) script would look for specific json files and combine them into one and place it under `apps/[app]/assets/i18n` so that the ngx-translate loader is still using one source for the app translations.

Also, as soon as a json file has been updated, the script should rewrite the existing file with the newly generated.

How would you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the exact same solution for a nx mono-repo for ngx-translate - and finally I found [ngx-translate-multi-http-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-translate-multi-http-loader)

You can create a non-buildable regular js nx lib for 'shared-translations', then add it to the assets array of the app's project json like so:

```
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "./libs/shared-translations/src/lib/assets/il8n/",
        "output": "./assets/shared/il8n/"
      }
```

The ngx-translate loader then just becomes:

```
export const translateHttpLoaderFactory = (http: HttpBackend): MultiTranslateHttpLoader => {
  return new MultiTranslateHttpLoader(http, [
    './assets/i18n/',
    './assets/shared/il8n/',
  ]);
};
```